# in chained promises, if first promise require to not to execute rest of the promises, how

Tags: javascript, promise

I have 4 methods that each return a Promise, and I have them in chain structure. But not I have a condition in very first Promise that can be satisfied, so in this case I need/should not execute remaining Promises in chain. How can I do this?

here are the 4 tasks that are being accomplished

task 1)see if the data exists in Mongo, if not

task 2) call the SOAP service

task 3) using the result from SOAP, manipulate data

task 4) put this document in Mongo

This works fine, but when task 1 has the data, then I should not process next 3 Promises (tasks 2, 3, 4).

Here is my current Code

```
checkMongoForData(req, res)
.then(function (result) {
   return makeTheSOAPcall(req, res, result)
.then(function (result) {
   return fillTheReasonDescriptions(req, res, result);
 })
 .then(function (result) {
   return upsertTheRespDocInMongo(req, res, result);
 })
 .then(function (result) {
   res.status(200);
   res.send({result: 'success', status: 200});
 })
 .catch(function (reject) {
   res.status(reject.status);
   res.send({result: reject.description, status: reject.status});
 });
```

// my functions defined something like this

```
function checkMongoForData(req, res) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
     // TODO : the logic goes here
     /// check to see for the data. If not there then continue
     // if there is data, no need to do remaining tasks
    });
 }
```

How do I achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: If there is data, call `reject()`.

Comment: In this case if your condition gets satisfied (you receive the data that you need) just do your task and leave the chained promises unresolved by neither resolving or rejecting.

Comment: Can you give more information on what you're trying to do? I'm thinking there may be some flaws in your design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, there are multiple ways to solve this problem.

One of them is by:

- Using an additional `catch()` after your "four tasks chain"
- "rejecting" (but not as an "error") the `getDataFromMongo` method in case
  of existing data (with a "dummy" error that we can actually check
  later)
- "duck-typing" the rejection cause of the chain itself

It's not the best one, but it won't break nor significantly change your existing chain of promises (if you are willing to change your chain, you should most likely go with [this answer by T.J. Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39724039/951007)):

```
// This can be anything, as long as it's "unique"
var dummyError = "has no data";

function checkMongoForData(req, res) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        // TODO: Replace with your logic
        var hasData = false;
        var data = "";

        if (hasData) {
            resolve(data);
        } else {
            reject(dummyError);
        }
    });
}

checkMongoForData(req, res)
    .then(function (result) {
        return makeTheSOAPcall(req, res, result)
    })
    .then(function (result) {
        return fillTheReasonDescriptions(req, res, result);
    })
    .then(function (result) {
        return upsertTheRespDocInMongo(req, res, result);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        if (error === dummyError) {
            return;
        }

        // This line "re-throws"/"re-rejects" the error object
        return Promise.reject(error);
    })
    .then(function (result) {
        res.status(200);
        res.send({result: 'success', status: 200});
    })
    .catch(function (reject) {
        res.status(reject.status);
        res.send({result: reject.description, status: reject.status});
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

> How can I do this?

Make `checkMongoForData` => `getDataFromMongo` and have it reject when it doesn't have the data. Then use `catch` to catch that rejection and fire off the chain of calls that gets the data:

```
getDataFromMongo(req, res)
    .catch(function() {
        // Didn't get the data, go get it
        return makeTheSOAPcall(req, res, result)
            .then(function (result) {
              return fillTheReasonDescriptions(req, res, result);
            })
            .then(function (result) {
              return upsertTheRespDocInMongo(req, res, result);
            });
    })
    .then(function (result) {
        // Got the data (one way or another)
        res.status(200);
        res.send({result: 'success', status: 200});
    })
    .catch(function (reject) {
        // Something went irretrievably wrong
        res.status(reject.status);
        res.send({result: reject.description, status: reject.status});
    });
```

If `upsertTheRespDocInMongo`'s resolution value isn't the data itself, you may need to add a `.then` on it to change what comes out.

Here's an example:

```js
var fakeMongo = Object.create(null);

function getDataFromMongo(key) {
    console.log("getDataFromMongo: ", key);
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(fakeMongo, key)) {
                // We have the data
                resolve({key: key, value: fakeMongo[key]});
            } else {
                // We don't have the data
                reject();
            }
        }, 100);
    });
}

function makeTheSOAPcall(key) {
    console.log("makeTheSOAPcall: " + key);
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        resolve({
            key: key,
            value: "value for " + key
        });
    });
}

function fillTheReasonDescriptions(result) {
    console.log("fillTheReasonDescriptions: " + result.key);
    return Promise.resolve(result);
}

function upsertTheRespDocInMongo(result) {
    console.log("upsertTheRespDocInMongo: " + result.key);
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        fakeMongo[result.key] = result.value;
        resolve(result);
    });
}

// Usage
retrieve("key1")       // Get key1 (won't be there)
  .then(function() {
    return retrieve("key2");  // Get key2 (won't be there)
  })
  .then(function() {   // Get key1 again (will be there)
    return retrieve("key1");
  })

function retrieve(key) {
    console.log("retrieve: " + key);
    return getDataFromMongo(key/*req, res*/)
        .catch(function() {
            // Didn't get the data, go get it
            return makeTheSOAPcall(key/*req, res*/)
                .then(function(result) {
                    return fillTheReasonDescriptions(/*req, res, */result);
                })
                .then(function(result) {
                    return upsertTheRespDocInMongo(/*req, res, */result);
                });
        })
        .then(function(result) {
            // Got the data (one way or another)
            console.log("Got the data:", result);
        })
        .catch(function(reject) {
            // Something went irretrievably wrong
            console.log("Somethingw went wrong", reject);
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I love ES6 as I think the code is more readable.

```
var reply = msg => {
  res.status(msg.status);
  res.send(msg);
};

var fetchAndUpdate = result =>
  makeTheSOAPcall(req, res, result)
  .then(result => fillTheReasonDescriptions(req, res, result))
  .then(result => upsertTheRespDocInMongo(req, res, result));

checkMongoForData(req, res)
  .then(result => 
     //This is the key change.  If result is not enpty, then return a promise
     //resolve, else call fetchAndUpdate which returns a promise, which will.
     //be resolved (or rejected) eventually.
     result ? Promise.resolve() : fetchAndUpdate(result))
  .then(() => reply({result: 'success', status: 200}))
  .catch(e => reply({result: e.description, status: e.status}));
```

ES5

```
var reply = function(msg) {
  res.status(msg.status);
  res.send(msg);
};
var fetchAndUpdate = function(result) {
  return makeTheSOAPcall(req, res, result).then(function(result) {
    return fillTheReasonDescriptions(req, res, result);
  }).then(function(result) {
    return upsertTheRespDocInMongo(req, res, result);
  });
};
checkMongoForData(req, res).then(function(result) {
  return result ? Promise.resolve() : fetchAndUpdate(result);
}).then(function() {
  return reply({
    result: "success",
    status: 200
  });
}).catch(function(e) {
  return reply({
    result: e.description,
    status: e.status
  });
});
```